# Mongoose not working with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reactjs

### Im trying to use mongoose to add a document to MongoDB, im also using react for the webpages, when i add this code into my jsx file

`var mongoose = require('mongoose')`

### it gives me a long list of errors:

```
WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js
Critical dependencies:
8:11-74 the request of a dependency is an expression
@ ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js 8:11-74

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/SPEC.md
Module parse failed: /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/SPEC.md Unexpected character '#' (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (2:0)
at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
at Parser.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:515:10)
at Object.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
at Parser.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
at nextLoader (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
at /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
at Storage.finished (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
at /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
@ ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/require_optional/index.js
Critical dependencies:
    63:18-42 the request of a dependency is an expression
71:20-44 the request of a dependency is an expression
78:35-67 the request of a dependency is an expression
@ ./~/require_optional/index.js 63:18-42 71:20-44 78:35-67

WARNING in ./~/require_optional/README.md
Module parse failed: /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/require_optional/README.md Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
at Parser.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:515:10)
at Object.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
at Parser.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
at nextLoader (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
at /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
at Storage.finished (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
at /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
@ ./~/require_optional ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/require_optional/LICENSE
Module parse failed: /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/require_optional/LICENSE Unexpected token (1:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:40)
at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
at Parser.pp.semicolon (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
at Parser.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
at Object.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
at Parser.parse (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
at nextLoader (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
at /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
at Storage.finished (/home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
at /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
@ ./~/require_optional ^\.\/.*$

ERROR in ./~/resolve-from/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'module' in /home/adam/code/Booking_App/node_modules/resolve-from
@ ./~/resolve-from/index.js 3:13-30
```

### This is my webpack config:

```
    var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './client/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './public/'),
        publicPath: './public/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json','.babel', '.node']
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        reasons: true,
        chunks: false
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.target.mk$/,
                loader: "raw-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.node$/,
                loader: "node-loader"
            },
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
};
```

#### im using react router with many jsx files to create my webpages, i also have a api thats got data from the database mongoose seems to work fine on there but not on any of the front end files

Comment: Is this an electron app?  If it's a webpage being built with react, you can't (and it's a bad idea) connect to a DB.

Comment: sorry it is a webapp

Comment: You don't want to be making DB calls from the client.  Keep that in your server.  Make the client call an API which will then communicate with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that mongoose is an abstraction layer on top of MongoDB, one of its dependencies is the MongoDB client, some of which is written in native code (C, C++).

**You cannot build** something like that with webpack.

Comment: mongodb client is written in JS